# Open terminal output in sublime2

Tags: gnome-terminal, text-editor, sublime-text, execute-command

I want to open the output of terminal commands in sublime2.

e.g. when I do `$ list` , it lists all files/folders in terminal. I want that when I run this command a temporary text file should be created and output is opened in sublime2 editor. I have no intention to save it. I just want to open output in sublime2.

I've seen that you can open in `textmate` in `Mac` by piping out the output.

`$ls | mate` ( I am not sure about the syntax )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a very simple script to do this.

Here is the script:

```
#! /bin/bash

"$@" > $$.txt
sublime-text $$.txt
rm $$.txt
```

Save it as `sublime.sh` (you can use any other name) and make it executable by running:

```
chmod +x sublime.sh
```

To use it:

```
./sublime.sh <command>
```

Example:

```
./sublime.sh ls -l
```

Explanation:

- Line 1 is the [shebang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29), which just specifies the interpreter.
- Line 3 runs the command that you passed and saves it in a file named `$$.txt`. `$$` returns the PID of the terminal you're using (feel free to use any other file name).
- Line 4 opens the file in `sublime-text`
- Line 5 deletes the file, since you don't want to save the file permanently.

---

**Update:** You can also put it in your `~/.bashrc` file to access it easily.

- Open a terminal.
- Go to home folder.

```
cd
```

- Open `.bashrc` file.

```
gedit .bashrc
```

- Copy the following at the end of the file.

```
function sublime()
{
    "$@" > ~/$$.txt
    sublime-text ~/$$.txt
    rm ~/$$.txt
}
```

- Run the following command to refresh:

```
. .bashrc
```

- Done!! Now use it:

```
sublime ls -l
```

Comment: 'I am new to ubuntu, so pardon my ignorance'.How can I make an entry in environment variable for this `.sh` file will be available in any directory (even after restart). I dont want to give path everytime.

Comment: updated the answer.

Comment: The command to open to sublime in my ubuntu is `sublime`. So, I did this 

`function sublimec()
{
    "$@" > ~/tmp/$$.txt
    sublime ~/tmp/$$.txt
    rm -rf ~/tmp/$$.txt
}`

I added a `/tmp` because it was saying permission denied, and thus I created a `/tmp` folder with permission for everyone. But, when I run `sublimec ls` , it continuously prints `permission denied message`

Comment: did you create the `temp` folder in your home directory?

Comment: ofcourse, I've created it and thus changed the permission too. Strange thing is that , it creates a <rand_no>.txt file in `tmp` folder along with the output of command. But whenever I run the command, the error shows up continuously (i.e. the error line is printed again and again like an infinite loop)

Comment: delete the folder and make it again. This time don't change the permissions.

Comment: works fine now. 

But I have one more problem now. It works fine when I open the terminal normally but fails when I open terminal from my keyboard shortcut which I use to open terminal in specific directory. I guess, its because `.bashrc` is not available in that terminal. Because when I do `.bashrc`, it says commandn not found. Can you rectify this issue ?

Comment: just copy paste the code in `/etc/bashrc` file.

Comment: I have `bash.bashrc` file in `/etc` . I copy-pasted in it. It works like a charm. I mark this as answer but can you please explain it ? Whats `"$@" > ~/$$.txt` ? Why I need to do `/etc/bash.bashrc` for custom terminal ? And why a copy-paste but not cut-paste from `/.bashrc` to `/etc/bash.bashrc`

Comment: `"$@"` expands to the command that you pass, so for example if you run `sublimec ls -l`, `"$@"` expands to `ls -l`. `$$` expands to the pid of the current shell. You can use any other file name. 

And `.bashrc` is used only by bash and bourne shell (I guess). Your custom shell won't use it. Also `.bashrc` makes changes only for the current user and not system-wide.

Answer (score 1):

I have used this method in the past to achieve what you want (I think)

```
ls -lrt > tmp.txt && gedit tmp.txt
```

obviously you need to change the reference to gedit so that it uses your prefered editor, in this case sublime.

My question would be what are you trying to achieve with this? It sounds like you are trying to record the output of your terminal sessions. If this is the case the you can use the "script" command

```
user@machine $ script ~/temp/terminal.txt
```

just type exit to quit recording

```
user@machine ~/temp $ exit
exit
Script done, file is /home/user/temp/terminal.txt
```

This should now mean terminal.txt contains a complete log of that session
hope this helps

Comment: what does this `-lrt` option do ? If I change your command for sublime like `ls -lrt > tmp.txt && sublime tmp.txt` it gives permission denied in directory where I dont have permission to create file. I dont want to do a sudo for that. I want to keep it simple.

Comment: -lrt is an option for the ls command it just orders the output, you can prefix the tmp.txt file location to a directory where you have write permission, such as ~/tmp.txt